# Is there a way to track generated page size with HTML/RUBY

Tags: ruby, haml

I want to paginate my web applications pages. But the usual get first 10 rows on first page, 10-20 in second page is not a wise decision for me, because my data is only text and varies a lot. One row can be only 10 byte long white another one 100kb long. So I want to paginate my applications pages by their size. For example when a page hits 300kb, i want HAML to notice it and flush the website.

The question is, is there a variable or function that i can check the generated pages size while the page is being generated?

Comment: Do you really care about the page size, or just the total size of the text you're pulling from the database to display in these rows?

Comment: well both will work for me, if i can get the text size i pull from the database while generating the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you're pulling the data from the database, just keep a running count of how much data you're outputting:

```
@some_collection.each_with_object(0) do |item, count|
  count += item.some_text_field.length + item.some_other_text_field.length
  break if count > 300
  # Proceed as usual
end
```

Note that the above counts the number of characters, not the number of bytes. If you want to count the latter you can call [`bytesize`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-bytesize) on each string instead of `length`.